# Adding a Bootstrap Tooltip to a view column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I'm trying to display a tooltip to my custom View column; ideally I'd like to use the Tooltip from ExtLib; however, I'm facing issues with its display since I'm not using oneUI themes; I'm using Bootrap 3.

I tried adding the css for dijitTooltip, but still the display is not working.

```
.dijitTooltip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: -10000px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.dijitTooltipRight { padding-left: 14px; }
```

My next attempt is using tooltip from Bootstrap; it works fine if I use simple text for tooltip content; however, I need to display dynamic content (using SSJS to get additional view information).

So I tried using data-html="true" and 'data-tile' or just 'title' attributes.

The only way I get it working is by using 'title', but the content is display as plain text and not as HTML.

[image]

```
<xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn10">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header"
                    id="viewColumnHeader10">
                </xp:viewColumnHeader>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:""}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:image url="/iconInfo16.png" id="imgInfo">
                <xp:this.attrs>
                    <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="tooltip"></xp:attr>
                    <xp:attr name="data-html" value="true"></xp:attr>
                    <xp:attr name="data-title">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"<b>html</b> code"}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:attr>
                    <!--<xp:attr name="title" value="test"></xp:attr>-->
                </xp:this.attrs>
            </xp:image>             
        </xp:viewColumn>
```

### Any ideas how can I solve this?

UPDATE:
This is how I solved it:

```
$(document).ready( 
function() {
    $(".tip").popover()})


<xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn10">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header"
                    id="viewColumnHeader10">
                </xp:viewColumnHeader>
            </xp:this.facets>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:""}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:image url="/iconInfo16.png" id="imgInfo"
                styleClass="tip">
                <xp:this.attrs>
                    <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="tooltip"></xp:attr>
                    <xp:attr name="data-html" value="true"></xp:attr>
                    <xp:attr name="data-trigger" value="hover"></xp:attr>
                    <xp:attr name="data-original-title" value="Special Comments"></xp:attr>
                    <xp:attr name="data-content">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("CourseName");}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:attr>

                </xp:this.attrs>
            </xp:image>
        </xp:viewColumn>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without diving into your own code I believe you're missing the function in bootstrap that makes the tooltip work.

I added the class="tip" to all my tooltips with this function

```
  $(function ()
  $(".tip").popover();
  });
```

You can find a working example on the table header in the first fieldset. [Working tooltip example](http://triplewww.com/cm/bs/cover.html)

Comment: Looks like html content within tooltip requires $(<selector>).popover() or $(<selector>).tooltip() It's working now. see my question update for final code.